# How can I prevent to watchers from firing in the same digest cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function `drawChart()` when either my string `chartTitle` or when any of the properties in my object `chartOptions` changes.

Watching them individually is easy:

```
$scope.$watch('chartTitle', drawChart);
$scope.$watchCollection('chartOptions', drawChart);
```

However, I need a way to combine them into one `$watch` statement (without adding `chartTitle` as a property of `chartOptions`.

How can I prevent both of these watchers from firing in the same digest cycle. That is, if I change both `chartTitle` and a property on `chartOptions`, how can I prevent `drawChart` from being called twice?

## Possible approaches:

- Do a deep watch on `chartOptions` and `chartTitle`. Unfortunately `chartOptions` is an extremely large and complicated object, so doing a deep watch on these properties is infeasible. *Is it possible to put a limit on how deep to go?*
- Detect in the `chartOptions` watcher whether `chartTitle` has been changed during this digest cycle, and vice versa. *Is this even possible?*
- Figure out a watch expression that would capture all the properties on `chartOptions` and `chartTitle`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a deep watch:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return {
            chartTitle: $scope.chartTitle,
            chartOptions: $scope.chartOptions
        };
    },
    function(newval) {
        ...
    },
    true // deep watch
);
```

Keep an eye for performance problems, it will be creating an object each digest cycle. Normally it won't matter, but for a heavyweight application it might.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good idea! Unfortunately in this case I can't use deep watches. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: What would also work is if there were a way to specify how deep to watch. I.e., watching with a depth of 2 would get me the chart title, and all the properties on chartOptions, but nothing deeper than that.

Comment: I do not have an answer for that, however I do not think it is feasible to watch without adding the watchers (1 deep or many shallow). The depth limiting idea is interesting; imagine, instead of the argument `true` for deep watch, to have the depth limit, e.g. `$scope.$watch("...", function(){...}, 2)`.

Comment: After some thought, I think the best way to do this is to create a new object with all the properties of `chartOptions` and an additional property `chartTitle`. Then I can do a `watchCollection` on that object. If `chartOptions` has many properties or is updated often this might not be performant, but I think it works. I'll leave the question up in case someone can think of something better.

Comment: Oh no! That strategy won't actually work. If `chartTitle` changes, the amalgam object will still be pointing to the old `chartTitle` value and will not trigger the watcher.

Comment: Try doing it like in the answer. Or, if doing it in every digest cycle hurts performance try *wrapping* the string in another object, placing the wrapper in your "amalgam" object, and only accessing the `chartTitle` through the wrapper.

Comment: Unfortunately a deep watch won't cut it for my case. `$scope.chartOptions` has moment objects at depth 2, which constantly trigger a digest cycle if you do object equality.

Comment: Upon further reflection I think something very similar to yours will work. Let me make an answer real quick

Answer (score 0):

Combine `chartTitle` and `chartOptions` into a single object, then do a `$watchCollection` on that object.

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    // Make a shallow clone of all the properties in chartOptions
    var amalgam = {};
    for (var key in $scope.chartOptions) {
        var val = $scope.chartOptions[key];
        amalgam[key] = val;
    }

    // Add the chart title to our shallow clone
    amalgam.chartTitle = $scope.chartTitle;
    return amalgam;
}, drawChart);
```

Note this may not be very fast as you are creating a new object every digest cycle.